# Reusing PCB Components

Tags: pcb-design

What are some good methods when considering designing an automated system which can efficiently recycle PCB’s to extract copper and the components from the PCB which can then be reused and recycled?

Comment: Why do this? Are you trying to make money? Save the environment? Reduce landfill trash or lead-poisoning in our water-supply? Provide an income for poor people? My reasons are all of the above. This automated method would have to be engineered, because it would be quite a challenge -- but it would be worth it from many perspectives. Thanks for your question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recovering for re-use (as repair parts, or for refurbishment and use in new PCBs) is inherently very labor intensive. I've seen some cottage industry smartphone breakers who recover clean and sort parts for sale in markets and online, some of the work literally done in alley ways. Most parts have no value, and some sub-assemblies such as mainboards are more valuable intact than dismembered, so it's not something that can easily be automated- it requires knowledge as well as labor to extract the value.

You can also hack off things that contain small amounts of precious metals such as gold fingers or connectors and attempt to recover (eg. chemically) the valuable elements. Again, labor and knowledge intensive particularly with a mixed input stream. Modern PCBs for consumer products contain very little in the way of precious metals (what looks like gold is probably just a thin layer a fraction of a nanometer thin on top of a layer of cheap nickel) so you'd have to process a **lot** of material to get a bit of recovered metal. That may be prohibitively expensive in places with strict (and strictly enforced) environmental laws (and insufficient subsidies to counteract the costs).

Comment: I want to figure out a way to do at least some of this. Power supplies are often modular enough to resell if verified or fixed. I thought that the best recycling would be to fix broken devices if possible. For the benefit of the environment, I would like to see things made more like the old-school tv's which last forever and are fixable.

Comment: One thing I did realize is that the price for a recycled item can be much lower and more reasonable. For instance, big beefy inductors are expensive, but trash is free. This enables a reasonably-priced killer Joule Thief kit to be sold (resold?) in the STEM, maker, or hobby markets. Everybody loves a good flashlight! ;-)

Comment: Repairing devices can be useful and entertaining. Some things have proprietary parts available even years after they were discontinued.  More mechanical or electro-mechanical than electronic but the German YT creator [Post Apocalyptic Inventor](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDbWmfrwmzn1ZsGgrYRUxoA) has some interesting resuscitations of scrapyard finds.

Comment: I'll check it out... Thank you, Spehro.